# Problems adjusting CSS, Wordpress Twentyfourteen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I am helping a friend fixing up a webpage, but are having some difficulties with the last adjustments. The site is based on Wordpress, and the Twentyfourteen theme. The page is found at centromariposa.no

Most of the adjustments have been done, but I can't seem to be able to do the last one properly.

The top looks like this now - the links are being "eaten" by the logo in smaller screens: imgur.com/oOnZspQ

When I adjust the paddings and margins on f.ex. ".primary-navigation .nav-menu" in the Inspect-console, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42msu.jpg

However, when I make those changes permanent, it ends up like this (or worse, all depending):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfSMK.jpg

Any input as to how I can achieve the middle picture?

Comment: Hi @Lars, this isn't really an appropriate question for SO. You need to try things first, show what you've tried and ask more targeted questions. Not ask the community to do the work for you. Thanks

Comment: Changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the site and here is what is my opinion:

- The logo's background image is **ON** the header not **IN** the header, thats why you cant controll it. move it to the `h1.siteclass` element inside your `header`
- The light blue is more in the left side because of the side bar if this is a custom sidebar(you edited it to have the content and sidebar in the same line) remove it and do it properly.. use bootstrap or use the themes sidebar option. if its by default like this, leave it as it is there no reason to fix this.
- For the menu style the site-header to have the height you want and then set a margin-top to the search-toggle and site-navigation.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - will try to change the menu now! The theme is like this by default, unfortunately. I've just been playing with margin and padding to try adjusting that.